# pst-barcode with MikTeX portable

Tags: xetex, miktex, pst-barcode

I have the following problem:

Rendering QR codes & Barcodes via psbarcode using Xelatex from Miktex portable just seems to work if the Windows path environment variable is set to MikTeX Portable location.

If its not set, everything else works fine but the barcodes just stay empty. Log file has no errors or warnings.
I also tried to call xelatex with "--include-directory=MikTeX_portable_path" argument, but it doesnt help...

Any ideas how to get around this?

This is a minimal example, how Im using psbarcode in my .tex files.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{pst-barcode,fancyvrb} 
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{.695\textwidth} 
    \flushright
    \tcbset{height=9cm, width=6.1cm,arc=0mm,
    colframe = black!0!white, colback=white}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[]
        \textbf{stuff1}\newline
        \textbf{stuff1}\newline
        \textbf{stuff2}\newline
        \begin{pspicture}(3,1in)
            %\psbarcode [Options] {text or ﬁlename}{PS options}{barcode type}
            \psbarcode{40841120}{height=1 width=2}{code128}
        \end{pspicture}\vspace{1.5cm}\newline
        %
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}m{2cm}>{\centering}m{2cm}@{}}   
            \begin{pspicture}(1in,0.8in)
                \psbarcode{40841120}{height=.8 width=.8}{qrcode}
            \end{pspicture}
            &%
            \fbox{
            \begin{minipage}[c][2cm][c]{2cm}
            \centering
            \centerline{\Huge{\textbf{TE}}}
            \end{minipage}}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}  
\vspace{-0.2cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you call xelatex when the parh is not set? Do you use the command line from miktex portable?

Comment: I navigate to the .tex file and call here the xelatex.exe with its absolute path in windows command line. And everything is working well except the barcodes. But as long as O have to set any variable on the system its not portable for me :(

Comment: You don't have to set the variable in the system. You can set it in the current command line window: set path=/path/to/miktex/bin;%path% and then a simple `xelatex file` should work. That is what the command line provided by miktex portable does.

Comment: Youre right, it works with miktex' own command line. Thank you!